# How to color a cube using glColorMaterial() calls in Android OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a cube that I want to paint with same color on all six sides. I must use `glColorMaterial()` calls (or `glMaterial()` ?) in order for lights to work correctly. If I use
`glColor4f()` call then this does not work with lights.
Can some help with providing me with sequence of commands to paint all six sides with 
`(1,0,0,1)`  red color and 100% opacity? This must work in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `glColorMaterial` to set specify the material parameters that should track the current color. For instance, use

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)
```

and then set the current color using `glColor4f(...)`. Don't forget the `glEnable` call!

Comment: Your answer works except I had to comment out gl.glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);  because Android does not support this. Not sure if this would have any other impact.

Comment: Ah, you're right of course, I mixed up regular OpenGL with OpenGL-ES. In OpenGL-ES, glColorMaterial is indeed not supported, and enabling GL_COLOR_MATERIAL will always make the ambient and diffuse materials track the current color. Sorry for the confusion ;-)